# Shading Problem: Mesh shading does not smooth, auto-smoothing is on

Tags: mesh, uv, shaders, lighting

I am looking to create a mesh that has smooth shading but I cannot figure out why my model has a massive lighting contrast.

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the normals of your mesh are calculated uniformly. Just select all in Edit mode(<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. The model should have adequate geometry as well. You should check for overlapping geometry, merge vertices by distance if needed with <kbd>M</kbd>  ->  <kbd>B</kbd> in edit mode. Also you have to make sure you you don't have anything weird going on in the shader, if you use normal maps, they should be in the right mode and their color space should also be set to Non Color.